# evaluating an operation with operators contained within a string

Tags: python

I have to evaluate an  expression, which uses operators that are stored in variables.

```
item1 = "*"
item2 = "+"
item3 = "/"
item4 = "-"
```

suppose I want to compute the value of 4*3-5/8, how could I do this with my string variables ?

Comment: Read about [eval](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#eval).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval):

```
>>> eval('5+4')
Out[15]: 9
>>> eval('5*4')
Out[16]: 20
>>> eval('5-4')
Out[17]: 1
```

Comment: Thanks BartoszKP and Steinar Lima, this what I was looking for :)